# DisplayTest sent null as its value

Tags: parameters, null, birt

I have a list box parameter (it allows multiple values). The parameter selects an INTEGER for the value column and a STRING for the display text.

I would like to print all the values from this list into the report.

I tried :

```
"Selected param(s) :" + params["param"].displayText.join(",");
```

But the displayText returned null... I don't know why!

So I tried using a list :

```
var paramCount = params["param"].value.length;
var param= parseInt(params["param"].value);
for( i=0; i < paramCount; i++ ){
    if(param== row["param"]){
        row["paramText"];
    }
}
```

I used the query I used to build the param. So row["paramText"] is the value in STRING and params["param"] is the value in INTEGER.

I added parseInt because my value print a object like : :`[Ljava.lang.Object;@6c8a3a0`. Even if I used the parseInt... It doesn't convert the value to int and prints NaN.

I just need to know why my displayText sent me null OR why my params["param"].value returns an object (and It doen't want to be converted)

If needed : I'm using BIRT 3.7.1

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that displayText seems have some defects. So I used a workarround : http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/19869-displaying-label-of-dynamic-parameter-list-box-in-report/

Comment: Can you please share the solution here? I've got problems registering to that forum... and I'm having similar issues.

Comment: I don't remermber exactly the workarround I used. But, on the report I download on http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/19869-displaying-label-of-dynamic-parameter-list-box-in-report/. I found on the "onFetch" method for the dataset a method to replace one word in the dataset. See, (credit to mwilliam : http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/user/3879-mwilliams/) : if (custList.indexOf(row["CUSTOMERNUMBER"].toString()) != null){
custList = custList.replace(row["CUSTOMERNUMBER"].toString(),row["CUSTOMERNAME"]);
}